# What happens if you're still in a dungeon after its availability ends?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Special Dungeons (not including Endless Corridor) have a limited duration of availability. Entering and exiting them is a formal, binding process. Usually, one can take as much time as they want in a dungeon; there's no time limit, except for the availability duration. Does it do anything like boot you out of the dungeon if you're still in it after its availability is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be kicked out of a Dungeon, regardless of its availability. Completely closing the app does not kick you out of a Dungeon.

How do I know? I completely closed Puzzle & Dragons while in [Dungeon of Emerald Dragons - Hunt Emerald Dragons!](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/mission.asp?m=261) after its hour of availability ended and remained there upon reopening P&D.
Edit: I still have accounts that are in [Snowy Village - Gather Round the Table](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/mission.asp?m=1074) that was available [2014-12-20T00:00-0800/2014-12-28T23:59-0800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals).

Answer (score 1):

**If your still in the dungeon and the availability ends, then you get kicked out of the dungeon and lose your progress.**

It's good to note that it is possible for it to be changed in a later patch, according to a comment on the wiki page:

> I think that limitation is changing in a future version, check the blog posts.

---

[Source](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Extreme_Hera_Rush!)

[Source 2](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Limited_Dungeon)

Comment: Had to test it empirically before I accepted, because I didn't see proof in your sources. Now I can personally confirm your assertion.

Comment: @NiteCyper Not to be a rep whore, but what was the reason of removing the "best answer"? I just want to improve my answers for the future, thanks.

Comment: Because I've found that this doesn't seem to be the case. I was running Dungeon of Emerald Dragons - Hunt Emerald Dragons! past the hour of availability and was not kicked out.